# Is there a better way to nest 500 if statements (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a better way to write 500 IF statements in Google Sheets? Right now, I am having it determine the maximum value from a row with 500 data points and display the name of the respective column's "title cell". Think of it like I am evaluating 500 baseball players for their batting average every year and want to display the name of the player who had the highest batting average for a given day and display the player's name.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en

Comment: Could you add some more detail, perhaps a small sample table?

Comment: I feel like if you're writing 500 `If` statements, there has to be a much better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Kindly include a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result